# Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Access to subscriberKey after link redirect

Tags: marketing-cloud

I was wondering is there any way to have access from JavaScript to the subscriberKey after users click an email redirect from email?
Obviously easiest solution is to embedded the %%subscriberKey%% as an url parameter, but I was wondering if it is not stored somewhere in the background already after click Marketing Cloud link?

And we are not using CloudPage of course.

Comment: Not sure if you just mean a link click in an email by "redirect", but if so, you need the _click data view: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&id=sf.mc_as_data_view_click.htm

Comment: Thanks for that! That great but not really exact what we need since we need to extract it via javascript in order to paste inside tracking collect code
I attached parameter manually and wrote that code:


_etmc.push(["setOrgId", "..."]);      
      if(sfmc_key != ''){_etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {"email": sfmc_key}]);}

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need to add the subscriber key to your links. This can be done utilising *Setup > Data Management > Parameter Manager > Web Analytics Connector*

The standard tagging looks like this:

```
utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=%%emailname_%%&utm_term=%%linkname%%&utm_id=%%jobid%%&sfmc_id=%%subscriberid%%
```

You can replace the parameters as you need, so let's add subscriber key for you to use upon click:

```
utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=%%emailname_%%&utm_term=%%linkname%%&utm_id=%%jobid%%&sfmc_id=%%subscriberid%%&skey=%%subscriberkey%%
```

Once this is updated, you will be able to append the subscriber key to your URLs. Once the visitor arrives on the page, you can use the below snippet to fetch the URL and pass it into `setUserInfo` call:

```javascript
var queryString = window.location.search;
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
var sfmc_key = urlParams.get('skey')
_etmc.push(["setOrgId", "..."]); 
if(sfmc_key != ''){
_etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {"email": sfmc_key}]);
}
```

Comment: Just to add that Web Analytics Connector would only add UTMs to the emails, so if the on the CloudPages should be updated manually and include SubscriberKey parameter as well.